# SpringBoot : Connection has already been closed

Tags: rest, spring-boot, connection-pooling, tomcat8, hana

I am getting exception below in my business flow very frequently.

Technical specifications are SprinBoot, Java8, SAP Hana as DB, Restful.

```
        org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JDBC transaction;
        nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed. at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:331) at 
            org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:853) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:830) at
            org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:536) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:286) at
            org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) at
            org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at
            org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) at
```

application.properties for data source

```
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.driver-class-name=com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.validation-query=select 1 from DUMMY 
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.test-while-idle=false
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.test-on-return=false
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.validation-interval=300000
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=300000
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.max-active=120
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.max-idle=40
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.initial-size=40
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.max-wait=600000
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.max-age=5000
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=600000
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.min-idle=40
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.log-abandoned=true
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.remove-abandoned-timeout=600
    SAPHanaViewDataSource.datasource.remove-abandoned=true
```

Am I doing some wrong configuration as per standards? Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: As the error says: "Connection has already been closed". We need more information about it in order to help you, because we can't guess why the connection has been closed :)

Comment: Hi Repikas : I do understand that Exception which I shared is too abstract. And from Exception message any one can say Connection which I established is closed and then I am trying to perform any DB operation.

But that's the Exception I am getting on Console. For more details we have configured DB configuration as part of DataSource in application.properties(SpringBoot). So I am looking for help in possible scenarios like any Configuration changes or any change which I can do in TransactionManager which is causing connection to get return to pool. etc.

Comment: Is there a maximum lifetime for connection that you can configure in Springboot? HANA allows for such configuration but it’s rare to find it active as it would affect all connections.

Comment: I have copied datasource configuration which I did in application.properties.